# Помогите разобраться с инкрементами и присваиванием.. JS

Tags: javascript, инкремент

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Есть код:

```
let counter = 1;
let a = counter++;
alert(a); //1
alert(a); //1
```

Однако если сделать

```
let counter = 1;
let a = counter++;
alert(counter++); //2
alert(counter++); //3
```

Хотя по сути код один и тот же. Почему разные результаты?

Я приведу немного другой пример:

```
let counter = 1;
let a = counter += 2;
//counter у нас стал 3 и запомнился
alert(a); //3 counter не изменился
alert(a); //3 counter не изменился
alert(counter); //3

let counter = 1;
let a = counter += 2;
//counter у нас стал 3 и запомнился
alert(counter += 2); //counter стал 5 и запомнился
alert(counter += 2); //counter стал 7 и запомнился
alert(counter); //7
```

То есть, если я правильно понимаю, если в коде явно не прописать само название переменной (например counter += 2), то ее использование в других переменных будет использовать последнее явно записанное состояние. В данном примере хоть а = counter += 2, то инкремент а не оказывает влияния на сам counter. Верно?

Comment: В смысле код один и тот же? Вы в первом случае вызываете оператор `++` один раз, во втором же случае три раза. (То-есть вам нужно убрать лишние операторы, чтобы результат получился тот же)

Comment: @ΝNL993 видимо ТС имеет ввиду почему во втором случае получается 3 без присвоения `a`, но тогда надо было `a` выводить

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Надо понимать, что инкремент, это не просто математическая операция, это в том числе и присвоение переменной. Иначе говоря, нет необходимости писать `counter = counter++`, `counter++` будет равнозначно `counter = counter + 1`.

Поиграйтесь с `++` до переменной и после. Если ставить после, то сначала возвращается значение переменной, а потом происходит инкремент. Поэтому у вас переменная `a` остаётся единицей, сам же `counter` будет равен 2, если вывести его в консоль в первом примере.

Во втором примере всё то же самое. У вас `a` будет равно единице, т.к. присваивается изначальное значение `counter`, а потом уже идёт инкремент. В первом `alert` он уже равен двум и инкрементируется, во втором трём, и опять же инкрементируется. В результате если вывести `alert(counter)` после всего, он будет равен 4.

Если же `++` ставить до переменной, то в `a = ++counter` в переменную `a` пойдёт результат инкремента.

---

По дополнению в вопросе, у вас нет инкремента `a`.

```
let a = counter += 2;
```

Код в данном случае необходимо читать справа налево. Т.е.:

1. Присваиваем переменной `counter` её же значение и `+2`. (`counter = counter + 2`)
   Тут стоит отметить, что `+=` и `=+` стоит читать иначе чем инкремент. `+=` — это присвоение с сложением, эквивалент выше в скобках. А вот `=+` — это оксюморон и расшифровывается как `counter = +counter`, где `+counter` не является сложением, а приведением к числовому типу. Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).
2. Присваиваем переменной `a` значение `counter`, посчитанное на шаге 1.

Иначе говоря, выражение можно переписать как:

```
let counter = 1;
let counter = counter + 2;
let a = counter;
```

Comment: Я кажется разобралась. Вопрос у меня скорее был в том, что если a = counter++, то почему если снова прописать а, это никак не повлияет на counter (хоть это подразумевается за кадром). Сложна :(

Comment: @jinx объяснил второй пример.